# Runtime error "parameter mismatch" using CallByName and Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've deleted my first attempt at asking this question, as I wasn't quite up to speed on the semantics.  Now I'm not much better.  Basically here's the issue.  I have a small block of online demo code that I'm analyzing that is showing how to access assembly-related functions in VB from C#. Basically loading and executing an assembly in C# using CallbyName to VB functions.  Here is the relevant code, with all variables defined:

```
// the only non-default usings for this code are:

using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Reflection;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     string exefile = Properties.Resources.binaryfile;

     // Convert base64 to bytes

     byte[] exe_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(exefile);

     // okay, the load call takes as an argument the byte array exe_bytes,
     // this makes sense

     object loaded = Interaction.CallByName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain, "load",CallType.Method, exe_bytes);

     // next, the entrypoint is taken from the loaded assembly, and
     // passed to the object entry

     object entry = Interaction.CallByName(loaded, "entrypoint", CallType.Get);

     // finally, invoke is called to execute it, being passed the 
     //  entrypoint.  But what are the null, null for?  This seems
     //  to be what is throwing the runtime error.

     object invocation = Interaction.CallByName(entry, "invoke", CallType.Method, null, null);
```

Okay, let me stop here to note a few things.  This builds successfully in C# (.NET 4.5), but throws a runtime error for parameter mismatch at the invocation line.  It seems to me from looking at the code that someone just put that into three separate lines (load,entrypoint,invoke) to demonstrate what they were doing, as we could substitute object definitions to create one line.  I add and subtract "nulls" from the 2 listed, and the error message remains, either saying it doesn't take 3 arguments, or that I erroneously have no arguments.

In my previous ask of the question a few hours ago, a helpful post suggested that I (quoting) "load the assembly (Reflection.Assembly.Load) and then inspect the parameters on the Assembly.EntryPoint property (MethodInfo) by calling its GetParameters method. Once you know what you are dealing with, then you can play with CallByName to start it." (credit to user TnTinMn)

So after about two hours of reading online docs with sparse examples, I've come up with only this line:

```
object loaded = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(exe_bytes);
```

to replace the loaded definition in the code.  After that, I have absolutely no idea what I am reading or doing!  Assembly.Entrypoint, GetParameters, MethodInfo, oh my!  Basically, I just want "how many parameters do you need? please print to console!" translated into C# .NET OO speak.  Because I am utterly lost.  Thank you!

The above seemed a good start, but alternative courses to a solution are certainly welcome.  If you can, please please provide code in your answer, as my ability translating tasks from concept to OO programming is noticeably deficient.

EDIT: This may be relevant for examining the number of parameters?

```
 MethodInfo[] methods = BUT_WHAT_OBJECT_GOES_HERE.GetMethods();
        foreach (MethodInfo info in methods)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(info.Name);
        }
```

In the example I took the code from, the object for the method GetMethods was a Program class.  I tried using the assembly object exefile and it won't take it.

Comment: Are your building the vb.net and c# with same version of Net?  You should not have to do anything fancy to get a c# and vb.net to work together using the same version of Net.  Not sure why you are using reflection methods when simple call should work.  CallByName is an over-kill.  You do have to be careful about parameter calling conventions but the compiler should handle it automatically provided you added the vb.net as a reference to the c# project and added the 'using' statement at top of module.

Comment: The only time I've had to use such things, like you are, is when I'm making VBA module function calls. Is this what you're doing? Otherwise, VB.NET functions should already be available to call without Reflection.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking this code was made deliberately verbose as a way of demonstrating various Callbyname usage, because as you say, there are much easier ways to accomplish this simple task.  Oddly enough, someone else said the code compiled and ran without any errors on their VS 2015 install, whereas my VS 2015 throws the runtime exception.  Both of us are building against .NET 4.5, and I'm not sure what other build/machine parameters would matter.

Comment: Retrieving the property "EntryPoint" on the loaded assembly yields a `MethodInfo` to the `static void Main` method.  A VB WinForm project using the default templates will have a `Main` method with a parameter named `Args` of type `System.String[]` (`static void Main(params String[] args)`).  When you call "Invoke" on this `MethodInfo` the 1st parameter is the instance to invoke it on; for a static method, you pass `null`.  The 2nd passed parameter is an Object array containing a value for each parameter the method expects.  For a default VB Winform app, this should a `String[]`.